# Expected [ '/' ] to be [ '/' ] - they look the same

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular2-routing, stub, angular2-testing

I'm trying to test a router outlet.

I originally had:

```
expect(landingPageLink).toBe('/', '1st link should go to landing page');
```

I was getting this error:

> Error: Expected [ '/' ] to be '/', '1st link should go to landing'.

So changed it to this:

```
expect(landingPageLink).toBe(['/'], '1st link should go to landing page');
```

Now I get this error:

> Error: Expected [ '/' ] to be [ '/' ], '1st link should go to landing
>   page'.

In the bottom error they look the same. How come it's not the same?

Full test:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js';

import {
    ComponentFixture,
    TestBed,
    async,
    fakeAsync
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
    DebugElement,
    Component,
    ViewChild,
    Pipe,
    PipeTransform,
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
} from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, RouterOutlet, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { NavbarComponent } from './shared/subcomponents/navbar.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RouterLinkStubDirective } from './router-stubs';
import { click } from './test/utilities.spec';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
    let appComponent: AppComponent;
    let navComponent: NavbarComponent;
    let appFixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
    let navFixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarComponent>;
    let debugElement: DebugElement;
    let element: HTMLElement;
    let linkDes: any;
    let links: any;
    let landingPageLink: any;
    let profileLink: any;
    let aboutLink: any;
    let findLink: any;
    let addLink: any;
    let registerLink: any;

    beforeAll(() => {
        TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
        TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
            platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
    });

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                AppComponent,
                NavbarComponent,
                RouterLinkStubDirective
            ],
            imports: [RouterTestingModule],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        appFixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        navFixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
        appComponent = appFixture.componentInstance;
        navComponent = navFixture.componentInstance;
        // trigger initial data binding
        appFixture.detectChanges();
        navFixture.detectChanges();

        // find DebugElements with an attached RouterLinkStubDirective
        linkDes = navFixture.debugElement
            .queryAll(By.directive(RouterLinkStubDirective));

        // get the attached link directive instances using the DebugElement injectors
        links = linkDes
            .map((de: any) => de.injector.get(RouterLinkStubDirective) as RouterLinkStubDirective);
        landingPageLink = links[0].linkParams;
        profileLink = links[1].linkParams;
        aboutLink = links[2].linkParams;
        findLink = links[3].linkParams;
        addLink = links[4].linkParams;
        registerLink = links[5].linkParams;
    });

    it('can get RouterLinks from template', () => {
        expect(links.length).toBe(6, 'should have 6 links');
        expect(landingPageLink).toBe(['/'], '1st link should go to landing page');
        expect(profileLink).toBe('/profile', '2nd link should go to Heroes');
        expect(aboutLink).toBe('/about', '3rd link should go to Heroes');
        expect(findLink).toBe('/find', '4th link should go to Heroes');
        expect(addLink).toBe('/add', '5th link should go to Heroes');
        expect(registerLink).toBe('/register', '6th link should go to Heroes');
    });

    it('can click find link in template', () => {
        expect(profileLink.navigatedTo).toBeNull('link should not have navigated yet');
        profileLink.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
        appFixture.detectChanges();
        expect(profileLink.navigatedTo).toBe('/find');
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to do a deep equal comparison.

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, changing toBe to toEqual fixed this. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Why Your First Attempt Fails

`['/']` is an array containing one element, the string: `'/'`.

`'/'` is a literal string.

Jasmine's `toBe()` matcher compares with `===`, not `==`, so your first comparison is equivalent to `['/'] === '/'`, which always fails.

## Why Your Second Attempt Fails

You can't compare two arrays directly with `===`; the result will always be false. So, your second comparison, which is equivalent to `['/'] === ['/']`, also fails.

## The Fix

Instead of `toBe`, use `toEqual`, which does deep comparisons. This means it can compare arrays and objects to check that their elements are equal. Example:

```
expect(landingPageLink).toEqual(['/'], '1st link should go to landing page');
```

All of this is [documented in the section "Included Matchers,"](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Included_Matchers) but not super-clearly.